# Can Windows boot from Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, windows, startup, ssd, windows-vista

I am thinking about using two SSDs. Install each OS on one SSD. Then set the boot order to the Ubuntu one first. Then, is it possible to boot Windows from Ubuntu? This should be simple right?

I will want it to always go to Ubuntu first, it only takes like 5 seconds for it to load anyways :)

Comment: This might be interesting: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/custom-unity-launcher-to-reboot-in.html ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you can run some Windows programs from Ubuntu using Wine. If you want to run the Windows operating system, however, I think you would have to use GRUB unless you want to run it virtually. Luckily, if you install Windows first and then install Ubuntu, Ubuntu will be the first option on the GRUB menu followed by safe mode and the recovery console and then Windows. So, if no key is pressed on boot up, Ubuntu will be your active operating system.

Comment: So if I install windows first on a HDD, and then Ubuntu it will automatically boot to Ubuntu unless I hold any key on my keyboard down? If true that sounds perfect!

Comment: won't it pause at the GRUB menu and wait for a choice? Would it be possible to make it go directly to Ubuntu with no menu?

Comment: It will pause for (I believe) 10 seconds by default and then the first option will automatically be selected. I have not used two hard drives before. You may need to be sure that your boot order in BIOS is set to the hard drive that contains your Ubuntu installation and GRUB first (or second to your optical drive). And, yes, you could eliminate the menu altogether, but then it would become difficult to get into Windows.

Comment: How difficult, couldn't I make an icon on my desktop and go straight to Windows from there? I thought I saw that for certain windows games where you could click on a game icon in Ubuntu and it would go straight to Windows and start the game up for you.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use virtualization environment.

You can install virtual box and then install windows os.

Comment: If I virtualize Windows then I can't play games on it :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SSD with Windows installed, you can add the drive it to /etc/default/grub, and run sudo update-grub.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to add windows specifically.

Also, you have 2 OS's on each SSD, right? Ubuntu should auto-detect Windows and by running sudo update-grub should add it to the list.

Personally I would just choose at startup (from BIOS).